# mysql most voted

Tags: mysql, vote

ID POST_ID

1  60
2  457
3  457
4  457
5  25
6  25

how i can get a list of most voted so the result would be :

457
25
60

Comment: Wouldn't the results be, `457, 60, 25`?

Comment: order is ok - number of counts for each post_id, 457 has 3 counts, so is at the top.

Comment: Ah, I see what the op is asking.

Comment: I think those are regular post. there are 3 items with post_ID 457, two with 25 and one with 60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id, count(post_id) num_votes 
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY post_id 
  ORDER BY num_votes DESC
```

will give you:

```
+---------+-----------+
| post_id | num_votes |
+---------+-----------+
| 457     | 3         |
| 25      | 2         |
| 60      | 1         |
+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  SELECT post_id 
    FROM my_table 
GROUP BY post_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
```

Comment: should be order by count(post_id)